# Bad migration need to fix mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Basically mistyped a migration and now I have a column in my `users` table like this: `{:index=>true}_id`

I am trying to remove this field in MYSQL terminal with:

```
ALTER TABLE 'users' DROP COLUMN '{:index=>true}_id';
```

**Error message:**

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ''users' drop column '{:index=>true}_id'' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backticks instead of single quotes.

```
ALTER TABLE `users` DROP COLUMN `{:index=>true}_id`;
```